# Unable to delete or modify PGP keys from Symantec Encryption Management Server using LDAP

Tags: java, android, ldap, pgp, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I want to delete or modify PGP public keys from SEMS server using LDAP. For these purpose i am using **LDAP SDK** from **UnboundID** and **Didisoft PGP java** library. When i am executing the codes both `connection.modify(request)` and `connection.delete(request)` are giving same result **Success** ,but not deleted from server, I still can see the keys on server. My code goes in this way.

**For Modification**

```
if (keyFound)
   {
     byte[] bytes = keyStr.getBytes();
     this.tmpKS.purge();
     KeyPairInformation[] keysTmp = this.tmpKS.importKeyRing(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
     KeyPairInformation tmpKeys = keysTmp[0];
     String certIdS = Long.toHexString(tmpKeys.getKeyID()).toUpperCase();
     for (int i = 0; i < 16 - certIdS.length(); i++) {
         certIdS = "0" + certIdS;
     }
     object = "pgpCertID=" + certIdS + "," + keysDn;
     ModifyRequest request = new ModifyRequest(object, new Modification[] { new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpCertID", certId), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpKeyID", key.getKeyIDHex()), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpKeyType", key.getAlgorithm()), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpKeyCreateTime", keyCreationTime), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpSignerID", certId), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpRevoked", key.isRevoked() ? "1" : "0"), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpCertID", certId), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpDisabled", "0"), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpKeyID", key.getKeyIDHex()), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpKeyType", key.getAlgorithm()), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpUserID", key.getUserID() + '\000'), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpSignerID", certId), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpKeySize", padLeft(key.getKeySize(), 5)), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpDisabled", "0"), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "objectClass", "pgpKeyInfo"), new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpKey", tmpOut.toByteArray()) });
     for (int i = 0; i < keysTmp.length; i++) {
       request.addModification(new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "pgpSubKeyID", Long.toHexString(keysTmp[i].getKeyID()).toUpperCase()));
     }
     LDAPResult result = connection.modify(request);
     return result.getResultCode().intValue() == 0;
}
```

and **For Delete Purpose**

```
if (keyFound)
{
    byte[] bytes = keyStr.getBytes();
    this.tmpKS.purge();
    KeyPairInformation[] keysTmp = this.tmpKS.importKeyRing(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    KeyPairInformation tmpKeys = keysTmp[0];
    String certIdS = Long.toHexString(tmpKeys.getKeyID()).toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16 - certIdS.length(); i++) {
        certIdS = "0" + certIdS;
    }
    object = "pgpCertID=" + certIdS + "," + keysDn;
    DeleteRequest request1 = new DeleteRequest(object);
    LDAPResult result1 = connection.delete(request1);
    LDAPResult result = connection.modify(request);
    return result.getResultCode().intValue() == 0;
}
```

LDAP Result:
**LDAPResult(resultCode=0 (success), messageID=3, opType='modify')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to remove an old key and push a new one is by revoking the old one, uploading it and afterwards uploading the new one.

In the case when you have lost the old private key nor having a revocation certificate then according to the PGP SDK from Symantec there is a method:

```
PGPDeleteFromKeyServer( PGPKeyServerRef     inKeyServerRef,
PGPKeySetRef    inKeysToDelete,
PGPKeySetRef *  outKeysThatFailed    
)
```

**Note**: The key server connection must have been established with an access type of kPGPKeyServerAccessType_Administrator.

If you establish an LDAP connection authenticated as admin LDAP user then you must be able to perform the delete operation.